# Union and Intersection of intervals

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I want to make this pictures below using tikz or pstricks. I know how to draw intervals using pstricks but unfortunately I am not able to draw intersections and union like done in the picture[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (-6,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (6,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
 \draw foreach \X in {-4,-3,...,4} {(\X,.1) -- (\X,-.1) node[below=0.2em]{$\X$}};
 \draw[very thick,red] (0,0.06) -- (4,0.06);
 \draw[very thick,red,{Bracket[width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[pos=3/4,above]{$J$};
 \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[reversed,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}] (-3.05,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=1/5,above]{$I$};
 \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (-3,0.5) -- (4,0.5) node[midway,above=0.1em]{$I\cup J$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (-6,0) node[below]{$-\infty$} -- (6,0) node[below]{$\infty$};
 \draw foreach \X in {-4,-3,...,4} {(\X,.1) -- (\X,-.1) node[below=0.2em]{$\X$}};
 \draw[very thick,red] (0,0.06) -- (4,0.06);
 \draw[very thick,red,{Bracket[width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[pos=3/4,above]{$J$};
 \draw[very thick,blue,{Bracket[reversed,width=1.2em]}-{Bracket[width=1.2em]}] (-3.05,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=1/5,above]{$I$};
 \draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (0,0.5) -- (2,0.5) node[midway,above=0.1em]{$I\cap J$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marmot